# What is respect?

Tags: definitions, meaning, concept, conceptual-analysis

“Respect”, “respectful”, and “disrespectful” are concepts we regularly hear being used, yet it has not always been clear to me if there is any essential underlying characteristic conveyed by these words, or if it is a meaningless stand-in for whatever the speaker subjectively happens to find respectful. Is there any candidate for a clear, evaluable criterion for the meaning of “respect”?

Comment: all i'm asking for (when i get home) https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/respect/

Answer (score -1):

Respect means to hold in admiration. For example - You may hold Jesus in admiration, you may hold your parents in admiration, you may hold your Boss in admiration, you may hold ex-President Donald Trump in admiration, you may hold Buddha in admiration , you may hold Einstein in admiration etc…

The meaning is quiet clear. Respect has depth. Sometimes your respect is so deep that you may give away your life for the one you respect.

Comment: I can respect a person without admiring them. I can actually detest a person's choices and still respect them, for example via rights.

Comment: How about respecting the law, or the rules of a game, or the rights of a person?

Comment: @armand Yes. Respecting Law , rules of a game and rights of a person is also possible.

Comment: What I mean is, are you admiring the red light when you wait before crossing?

Comment: @armand No , you are not admiring red light. You admiring the constitution of the land.

Comment: Sounds far fetched. I have respected rules I consider pretty stupid. Admiration simply has nothing to do with it